# How are node.js callbacks asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have recently started with node.js. It quotes that node.js asynchronous behaviour can be used in three ways `events`, `stream`, `callback`.

Events and stream work on `emit,pipe` event making it truly async, but how is callback async, as it **executes** before the return of the function unless **process.nextTick()** is used.

Events:

```
event.on('data',function(data){

});
```

Callback:

```
function(data,cb){
 // do something with "data"
 cb();
 return;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a closer look at your function that has a callback:

```
function(data, cb) {
 // do something with "data"
 cb();
 return;
}
```

You have 2 big errors here:

1) You have no reason to use return when you have a callback function. Return is used only when you have synchronous actions that send a response back right away (they do not have to wait for a callback to be triggered sometime in the future).

2) You don't execute the callback immediately, it doesn't make any sense. You either don't use a callback and use a return statement (when you don't really have an async function) or you execute the callback sometime in the future, when you get the result.

Better example:

```
function (data, cb) {
  // you make an Ajax call and 
  // you don't know when the callback will be triggered
  makeAjaxCall(data, cb);
}
```

Comment: You can very reasonably return something with an asynchronous action, e.g. you might return `this` allowing for method chaining.

Comment: @lanzz: sounds like a great recipe for race conditions though.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt I think it would be quite contrived to cause a race condition in event-driven single-threaded code. Also, how is `object.method1().method2()` more prone to race conditions than `object.method1(); object.method2()`?

Comment: Sorry about lot of mistakes.                                          I think question being misunderstood. example was just for posterity. @alessioalex:  isn't function is sync, passing `cb` as just scope, main function cannot return until makeAjaxCall completes, but by then `callback` is already called, if it is not event based or we delay it till nextTick. I have seen many node modules where return is used after callback for chaining.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in that callbacks don't necessarily mean asynchronous I/O.

Events aren't necessarily asynchronous either, in the sense that EventEmitter's .emit works immediately, not on the next tick:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

var emitter = new EventEmitter();

emitter.on('ev', function(x) { 
    console.log("received event ", x);
});

console.log("Hello");
emitter.emit('ev', "X");
console.log("World");
```

Result:

```
Hello
received event  X
World
```

However, callbacks *can* be made "async" by:

- using process.nextTick(). This doesn't make the actual I/O operations inside the callback async. It just defers execution until the next tick. If some operation blocks, the event loop will also block - on the next tick instead of this tick.

  ```
  function(data, cb) {
      process.nextTick(function() { doSomethingWith(data); cb(); })
  });
  ```
- calling the specified callback function from an event that is known to be triggered by an async I/O operation

  ```
  function(data, cb) {
      emitter.startIO();
      emitter.on('someIOEvent', function(e) { 
          doSomethingWith(data,e); 
          cb(); 
      });
  });
  ```
- using another callback-based function known to be async. Most functions in node core and node's modules are like this.

  ```
  function(data, cb) {
      otherFunction(data, function(moredata) { 
          doMoreStuffWith(moredata, data); cb(); 
      });
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the function with the callback is not being run asynchronously, however there are still cases where such functions can be used asynchronously:

```
function foo(data, callback) {
    // do something with the data
    callback();
}

function bar() {
    // this will be called as a callback from foo()
}

setInterval(function() { foo(data, bar) }, 1000);
console.log('this is displayed immediately');
```

You can see that `foo()` is scheduled to run every second, and that happens asynchronously; however the existence of the callback allows you to set up extra behavior from outside the `foo()` function, e.g. you might set up several cases where `foo()` is called with different callbacks, resulting in different application logic.